# Responsive Email Template Bugs

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, inline

I am working on an email template and am having three issues I cannot seem to figure out.

1. Image at top is being stretched.
2. Email is not responsive in Gmail App (landscape)
3. Left aligned text is correct in larger screens, but off centered in mobile screens. (Need to disable added margin in mobile screens)

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">  <!-- Disable auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail entirely -->
    <title></title> <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->

    <!-- Web Font / @font-face : BEGIN -->
    <!-- NOTE: If web fonts are not required, lines 10 - 27 can be safely removed. -->
    
    <!-- Desktop Outlook chokes on web font references and defaults to Times New Roman, so we force a safe fallback font. -->
    <!--[if mso]>
        <style>
            * {
                font-family: sans-serif !important;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
    
    <!-- All other clients get the webfont reference; some will render the font and others will silently fail to the fallbacks. More on that here: http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2015/02/webfont-support-in-email/ -->
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <!-- insert web font reference, eg: <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <!-- Web Font / @font-face : END -->
    
    <!-- CSS Reset -->
    <style>

        /* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
        /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }
        
        /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }
        
        /* What it does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
        div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
            margin:0 !important;
        }
        
        /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }
                
        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        table table table {
            table-layout: auto; 
        }
        
        /* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
        }
        
        /* What it does: A work-around for iOS meddling in triggered links. */
        .mobile-link--footer a,
        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color:inherit !important;
            text-decoration: underline !important;
        }
        
        /* What it does: Prevents underlining the button text in Windows 10 */
        .button-link {
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }
      
    </style>
    
    <!-- Progressive Enhancements -->
    <style>
        
        /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */
        .button-td,
        .button-a {
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        }
        .button-td:hover,
        .button-a:hover {
            background: #555555 !important;
            border-color: #555555 !important;
        }

        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
            .fluid {
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }
        
            /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
            .center-on-narrow {
                text-align: center !important;
                display: block !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }
            table.center-on-narrow {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }
                
        }
    
    </style>

</head>
<body width="100%" bgcolor="#f1f1f1" style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
    <center style="width: 100%; background: #f1f1f1;">

        <!--    
            Set the email width. Defined in two places:
            1. max-width for all clients except Desktop Windows Outlook, allowing the email to squish on narrow but never go wider than 680px.
            2. MSO tags for Desktop Windows Outlook enforce a 680px width.
            Note: The Fluid and Responsive templates have a different width (600px). The hybrid grid is more "fragile", and I've found that 680px is a good width. Change with caution.  
        -->
        <div style="max-width: 680px; margin: auto;">
            <!--[if mso]>
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="680" align="center">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <![endif]-->

            <!-- Email Header : BEGIN -->
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 680px;">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#222944" style="padding: 20px 0; text-align: center">
                        <img src="http://revrails-production.s3.amazonaws.com/marketing/emails/template/RevolutionPrep_Logo.png" width="200" height="50" alt="alt_text" border="0" style="height: auto; background: #222944; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Email Header : END -->

            <!-- Clear Spacer : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td height="15" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                     
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Clear Spacer : END -->

            <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 680px;">
            
                <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="vero-editable" style="padding: 40px 40px 0px 40px; text-align: center; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 24px; color: black;">
                                    <h1 style="color: black; font-size: 24px; font-weight: normal;letter-spacing: 1px; padding-bottom: 0px; line-height: 30px;">Thank you <nobr>for getting in</nobr> touch!</h1>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : END -->
               
                <!-- 3 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
                <tr>

                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 20px;">
                        <img src="http://revrails-production.s3.amazonaws.com/marketing/emails/template/email_envelope.png" width="170" height="" border="0" alt="alt_text" class="center-on-narrow" style="width: 100%; max-width: 170px; height: auto; background: #fff;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 3 Even Columns : END -->
                
                <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="vero-editable" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0px 40px 40px 40px; text-align: left; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 24px; color: black;">
                                <p>
                                We have received your message and would like to thank you for writing to us. If your inquiry is urgent, please use the telephone number listed below, to talk to one of our staff members. In the meantime, you can check the FAQ section, look over advice and planning that we offer for free or browse through our latest blog posts click here. Otherwise, we will reply by email shortly.
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                Talk to you soon,
                                <br>
                                Revolution Prep Team
                                </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : END -->

                <!-- Clear Spacer : BEGIN -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="15" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                         
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Clear Spacer : END -->

                <!-- 2 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#cfd4d8" align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%">
                        <!--[if mso]>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="660">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" width="660">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width:660px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:0; padding: 10px 0;">
                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="padding-left:-30px;" width="660">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="330">
                                    <![endif]-->
                                    <div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; width:100%; min-width:200px; max-width:330px; vertical-align:top;" class="stack-column">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 25px 10px 0px 30px;">
                                                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-size: 14px;text-align: left;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; mso-height-rule: exactly; color: #222944; text-align: left; letter-spacing: .5px;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                              Revolution Prep
                                                              <div style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; mso-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 18px; color: #455560;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                              1337 3<sup>rd</sup> Street Promenade, <nobr>2<sup>nd</sup> Floor</nobr>
                                                              <br>
                                                              Santa Monica, CA 90401<br>
                                                              <a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204;">revolutionprep.com</a>
                                                              </div>
                                                              <br>
                                                              <div style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; mso-height-rule: exactly; color: #222944; text-align: left; letter-spacing: .5px;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                              Need help?
                                                              <div style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; mso-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 18px; color: #455560;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                              Call us at <strong>(877) 738-7737</strong> or
                                                              <br>
                                                              <a href="mailto:answers@revolutionprep.com" style="color:#fd8204;">Email us</a> with any questions.
                                                              </div>
                                                              <br>
                                                              <div style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; mso-height-rule: exactly; color: #222944; text-align: left; letter-spacing: .5px; padding-bottom: 8px;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                              Follow us
                                                              </div>
                                                              <a href="http://twitter.com/revolutionprep?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email"><img src="http://assets.getvero.com/emails/templates/welcome/tw.png" style="padding-right: 5px" alt="Twitter" height="27px" width="26px"></a>
                                                              <a href="http://www.facebook.com/RevolutionPrep?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email"><img src="http://assets.getvero.com/emails/templates/welcome/fb.png" alt="Facebook" height="27px" width="26px"></a>
                                                              </div>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="330">
                                    <![endif]-->
                                    <div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; width:100%; min-width:200px; max-width:330px; vertical-align:top;" class="stack-column">
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 25px 10px;">
                                                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-size: 14px;text-align: left;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 14px; color: #555555; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                            <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/about-us/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">About Revolution</a></div>
                                                            <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/how-it-works/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">How We Work</a></div>
                                                            <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/find-a-tutor/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">Subjects we Tutor</a></div>
                                                            <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/success-stories/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">Success Stories</a></div>
                                                            <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/advice-and-planning/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">Advice and Planning</a></div> 
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]-->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--[if mso]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 2 Even Columns : END -->

                <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#fd8204">
                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 20px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 1px; line-height: 20px;text-align: center; color: white;">
                                    <nobr>BETTER GRADES.</nobr>  <nobr>HIGHER TEST SCORES.</nobr>  <nobr>GREATER CONFIDENCE.</nobr>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->

            </table>
            <!-- Email Body : END -->
          
            <!-- Email Footer : BEGIN -->
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 680px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 10px;width: 100%;font-size: 12px; font-family: sans-serif; line-height:18px; text-align: center; color: #888888;">
                        <a style="color:#888888; text-decoration:underline;" href="{{url.unsubscribe_link}}">Click here to unsubscribe
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Email Footer : END -->

            <!--[if mso]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

### Mobile left-align bug -

[image: Mobile left-align bug -]

### Outlook left-align bug -

[image: Outlook left-align bug -]

### Mobile Gmail App header stretched and white space to right (non-responsive) -

[image: Mobile Gmail App header stretched and white space to right (non-responsive) -]

Answer (score 0):

For the left-align bug, I think you do it little bit wrong. Try this.

```
<td style="padding: 20px 10px 0px 30px;">
    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-size: 14px;text-align: left;">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 14px; color: #555555; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/about-us/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">About Revolution</a></div>
                <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/how-it-works/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">How We Work</a></div>
                <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/find-a-tutor/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">Subjects we Tutor</a></div>
                <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/success-stories/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">Success Stories</a></div>
                <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/advice-and-planning/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">Advice and Planning</a></div> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

I just modify the padding. Hope it will help. I can't help you for your first issue, because I had checked and run your code at jsfiddle, nothing wrong with the image issue that you said :/

Answer (score 0):

For the image stretching part, have you tried removing the `font-size` and `line-height` on the image?  Since it is an image it really doesn't need it.  Gmail App adds weird font-sizes sometimes so that may be the cause.

I agree with the other answer above on the misaligned mobile stuff.  You have different padding on each column.  See column one you have `padding: 25px 10px 0px 30px;`

Answer (score 0):

1. For the top image, you need to add 'height' (height=170, style=height:170px) like this;

```html
<img src='http://revrails-production.s3.amazonaws.com/marketing/emails/template/email_envelope.png' width='170' height='170' border='0' alt='' class='center-on-narrow' style='width: 100%; max-width: 170px; height: auto; max-height:170px; background: #fff;'>
```

I've tested all browser in Litmus, they are all good.

2. For Gmail App(Android), you need to add 'hack' code below body tag. And you need to add style for 'gmailfix' class like this in the style tag. After adding this code, Grail app renders like desktop version.

```html
...

<style>

        .gmailfix {display:none;display:none!important;}
</style>

...
...

<body width="100%" bgcolor="#f1f1f1" style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
<!-- below is hack for gmail app -->
  <div class="gmailfix" style="white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; line-height:0;">
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
</div>
  
...
...
```

3. Here is all code that I have fixed. You can copy this code and test in Litmus. I have tested in all email client and eveything looks good.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">  <!-- Disable auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail entirely -->
    <title></title> <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->

    <!-- Web Font / @font-face : BEGIN -->
    <!-- NOTE: If web fonts are not required, lines 10 - 27 can be safely removed. -->

    <!-- Desktop Outlook chokes on web font references and defaults to Times New Roman, so we force a safe fallback font. -->
    <!--[if mso]>
        <style>
            * {
                font-family: sans-serif !important;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- All other clients get the webfont reference; some will render the font and others will silently fail to the fallbacks. More on that here: http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2015/02/webfont-support-in-email/ -->
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <!-- insert web font reference, eg: <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <!-- Web Font / @font-face : END -->

    <!-- CSS Reset -->
    <style>

        /* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
        /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        /* What it does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
        div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
            margin:0 !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        table table table {
            table-layout: auto; 
        }

        /* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
        }

        /* What it does: A work-around for iOS meddling in triggered links. */
        .mobile-link--footer a,
        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color:inherit !important;
            text-decoration: underline !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Prevents underlining the button text in Windows 10 */
        .button-link {
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }

    </style>

    <!-- Progressive Enhancements -->
    <style>

        /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */
        .button-td,
        .button-a {
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        }
        .button-td:hover,
        .button-a:hover {
            background: #555555 !important;
            border-color: #555555 !important;
        }
        .gmailfix {display:none;display:none!important;}

        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
            .fluid {
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
            .center-on-narrow {
                text-align: center !important;
                display: block !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }
            table.center-on-narrow {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }

            .mcenter, .mcenter * {text-align: center !important;}

        }

    </style>

</head>
<body width="100%" bgcolor="#f1f1f1" style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
<div class="gmailfix" style="white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; line-height:0;">
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    </div>

    <center style="width: 100%; background: #f1f1f1;">

        <!--    
            Set the email width. Defined in two places:
            1. max-width for all clients except Desktop Windows Outlook, allowing the email to squish on narrow but never go wider than 680px.
            2. MSO tags for Desktop Windows Outlook enforce a 680px width.
            Note: The Fluid and Responsive templates have a different width (600px). The hybrid grid is more "fragile", and I've found that 680px is a good width. Change with caution.  
        -->
        <div style="max-width: 680px; margin: auto;">
            <!--[if mso]>
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="680" align="center">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <![endif]-->

            <!-- Email Header : BEGIN -->
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 680px;">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#222944" style="padding: 20px 0; text-align: center">
                        <img src="http://revrails-production.s3.amazonaws.com/marketing/emails/template/RevolutionPrep_Logo.png" width="200" height="50" alt="alt_text" border="0" style="height: auto; background: #222944; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Email Header : END -->

            <!-- Clear Spacer : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td height="15" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                     
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Clear Spacer : END -->

            <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 680px;">

                <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="vero-editable" style="padding: 40px 40px 0px 40px; text-align: center; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 24px; color: black;">
                                    <h1 style="color: black; font-size: 24px; font-weight: normal;letter-spacing: 1px; padding-bottom: 0px; line-height: 30px;">Thank you <nobr>for getting in</nobr> touch!</h1>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : END -->

                <!-- 3 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
                <tr>

                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 20px;">
                        <img src="http://revrails-production.s3.amazonaws.com/marketing/emails/template/email_envelope.png" width="170" height="170" border="0" alt="alt_text" class="center-on-narrow" style="width: 100%; max-width: 170px; height: auto; max-height:170px; background: #fff;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 3 Even Columns : END -->

                <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="vero-editable" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0px 40px 40px 40px; text-align: left; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 24px; color: black;">
                                <p>
                                We have received your message and would like to thank you for writing to us. If your inquiry is urgent, please use the telephone number listed below, to talk to one of our staff members. In the meantime, you can check the FAQ section, look over advice and planning that we offer for free or browse through our latest blog posts click here. Otherwise, we will reply by email shortly.
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                Talk to you soon,
                                <br>
                                Revolution Prep Team
                                </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : END -->

                <!-- Clear Spacer : BEGIN -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="15" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                         
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Clear Spacer : END -->

                <!-- 2 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#cfd4d8" align="center" height="100%" valign="top" width="100%">
                        <!--[if mso]>
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="660">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" width="660">
                        <![endif]-->
                        <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width:660px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:0; padding: 10px 0;">
                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                    <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="padding-left:-30px;" width="660">
                                    <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="330">
                                    <![endif]-->
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;width:100%;max-width:300px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left" style="padding: 25px 10px 0px 30px;">
                                                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-size: 14px;text-align: left;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; mso-height-rule: exactly; color: #222944; text-align: left; letter-spacing: .5px;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                              Revolution Prep
                                                              <div style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; mso-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 18px; color: #455560;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                              1337 3<sup>rd</sup> Street Promenade, <nobr>2<sup>nd</sup> Floor</nobr>
                                                              <br>
                                                              Santa Monica, CA 90401<br>
                                                              <a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204;">revolutionprep.com</a>
                                                              </div>
                                                              <br>
                                                              <div style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; mso-height-rule: exactly; color: #222944; text-align: left; letter-spacing: .5px;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                              Need help?
                                                              <div style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; mso-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 18px; color: #455560;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                              Call us at <strong>(877) 738-7737</strong> or
                                                              <br>
                                                              <a href="mailto:answers@revolutionprep.com" style="color:#fd8204;">Email us</a> with any questions.
                                                              </div>
                                                              <br>
                                                              <div style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; mso-height-rule: exactly; color: #222944; text-align: left; letter-spacing: .5px; padding-bottom: 8px;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                              Follow us
                                                              </div>
                                                              <a href="http://twitter.com/revolutionprep?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email"><img src="http://assets.getvero.com/emails/templates/welcome/tw.png" style="padding-right: 5px" alt="Twitter" height="27px" width="26px"></a>
                                                              <a href="http://www.facebook.com/RevolutionPrep?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email"><img src="http://assets.getvero.com/emails/templates/welcome/fb.png" alt="Facebook" height="27px" width="26px"></a>
                                                              </div>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="330">
                                    <![endif]-->
                                    
                                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;width:100%;max-width:190px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left" style="padding: 25px 10px 0px 30px;">
                                                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-size: 14px;text-align: left;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 14px; color: #555555; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                                            <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/about-us/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">About Revolution</a></div>
                                                            <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/how-it-works/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">How We Work</a></div>
                                                            <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/find-a-tutor/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">Subjects we Tutor</a></div>
                                                            <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/success-stories/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">Success Stories</a></div>
                                                            <div style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="https://www.revolutionprep.com/advice-and-planning/?utm_source=vero&amp;utm_campaign=footer&amp;utm_medium=email" style="color:#fd8204; margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; font-size:13px;" target="_blank">Advice and Planning</a></div> 
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <![endif]-->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--[if mso]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 2 Even Columns : END -->

                <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#fd8204">
                        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 20px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 1px; line-height: 20px;text-align: center; color: white;">
                                    <nobr>BETTER GRADES.</nobr>  <nobr>HIGHER TEST SCORES.</nobr>  <nobr>GREATER CONFIDENCE.</nobr>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->

            </table>
            <!-- Email Body : END -->

            <!-- Email Footer : BEGIN -->
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 680px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 10px;width: 100%;font-size: 12px; font-family: sans-serif; line-height:18px; text-align: center; color: #888888;">
                        <a style="color:#888888; text-decoration:underline;" href="{{url.unsubscribe_link}}">Click here to unsubscribe
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Email Footer : END -->

            <!--[if mso]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```